# How to aggregate group of rows by a irregular interval in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, character, text-mining

I have a data frame with lines of a transcription of a conversation, in which what was said by each person is separated by an empty line. I now need to aggregate the lines so that each one is a row, but the line ranges are irregular. How can I aggregate this data?

The data are like this:

| Speech | Sep line |
| --- | --- |
| Was in Augoust | 0 |
| Don't you remember? | 0 |
|  | 1 |
| Yes, i did | 0 |
| It was a hot Saturday | 0 |
| we were in the park | 0 |
|  | 1 |
| That's right | 0 |
| it was a fun day | 0 |

I want the date to be like:

| speech |
| --- |
| Was in Augoust, Don't you remember? |
| Yes, i did. It was a hot Saturday, we were in the park |
| That's right,it was a fun day |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = cumsum(sep_line)) %>% 
  filter(sep_line == 0) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(
    speech = paste(speech, collapse = " ")
  ) %>% 
  select(speech)
```